# How to change color of text based on text-value by using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have table data which shows football team statistics.

There is column which have letters like:

1. "W" (win)
2. "L" (lose)
3. "D" (draw)

That's letters are rendered as a separate column, thing is that value is dynamically, and I need to apply different colors:

1. In case with "W" that text should be green
2. In case with "L" color red
3. In case with "D" color grey

Is there are way to do that trough CSS?

```
.table td:nth-child(3) {
  if letter is === W apply green color?
}
```

```
<td>
  "W"
</td>     
<td>
  "L"
</td>  
<td>
  "D"
</td>
```

[image]

Comment: Add a class to their container when outputting them to the page dynamically. I'm not sure how they're pulled and inserted so it's difficult to say exactly.

Comment: Can I add a class to the <td> and then trough class get access to content of filed and then change the color based on value of content?

Comment: You can just style the class `.letter-w { color: green }` etc. are you using JavaScript or PHP to dynamically insert the data? Guessing JS and you're hitting an external API for the scores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can pass those letters as an attribute to the td element you can do it in CSS like this:

```
 <td color_code='Your letter'>Your letter</td>
```

here 'your letter' is the letter that's generated dynamically. Now, simply in CSS, just specify that attribute when calling the td element:

```
td[color_code='L']{ color: red}
```

and the same for the rest of the letters.

Comment: To be html5 conform, you should use   <td data-color-code="W" ...., not color_code.

Comment: you're right but I tried it this way and it worked with no errors. anyway, your way is better, thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 2):

If you can add an attribute, you can target the attribute in CSS for different style rules. Example

```
 <td data-result-val="W">W</td>
 <td data-result-val="L">L</td>
 <td data-result-val="D">D</td>
```

in css

```
 td[data-result-val="L"] { color: red;}
 td[data-result-val="W"] { color: green;}
 td[data-result-val="D"] { color: grey;}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible any more. The contains pseudo class can do this, but this is deprecated and will not work any more.

What you can do:

Best solution:

When rendering the page, you can render a class at the td:  < td class="color-W">W> < /td>.

Not so good:

Or you can set the classes after rendering with javascript or jQuery.

JQuery:

```
$('td:contains("W")').addClass('color-W');
```

P.S.:  the jQuery :contains pseudo class selector is parsed by jQuery and works fine.